# Como retornar a página no LARAVEL 5.4

Tags: php, return, laravel-5.4

Estou com um problema, estou com 4 tabela, Cursos, disciplinas, professores e templates, cada qual com uma página para si, quando eu altero ou excluo algo em disciplinas, professores eu retorno para a página cursos, eu quero retornar para a própria página. 
Estou usando o `laravel 5.4`

```
 <!-- Cursos -->
            <div id="Cursos" class="tab-info" style="display:block;">
                @if(session('message'))
                    <p class='box-alert-info'>{{ session('message') }}</p>
                @endif
                @if(session('error'))
                    <p class='box-alert-error'>{{ session('error') }}</p>
                @endif
                <p><a href='#' class='modal-btn button special icon fa-plus' name='novoCurso'>Novo curso</a></p>
                <div class="table-wrapper">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Curso</th>
                                <th>Editar</th>
                                <th>Excluir</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($cursos as $curso)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $curso->nome }}</td>
                                    <td><a href="/administrador/cursos/editar/{{ $curso->id }}">Editar</a></td>
                                    <td><a href="/administrador/cursos/deletar/{{ $curso->id }}">Excluir</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Disciplinas -->
            <div id="Disciplinas" class="tab-info">
                @if(session('message'))
                    <p class='box-alert-info'>{{ session('message') }}</p>
                @endif
                @if(session('error'))
                    <p class='box-alert-error'>{{ session('error') }}</p>
                @endif
                <p><a href='#' class='modal-btn button special icon fa-plus' name='novaDisciplina'>Nova disciplina</a></p>
                <div class="table-wrapper">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Disciplina</th>
                                <th>Editar</th>
                                <th>Excluir</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($disciplinas as $disciplina)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $disciplina->nome }}</td>
                                    <td><a href="/administrador/disciplinas/editar/{{ $disciplina->id }}">Editar</a></td>
                                    <td><a href="/administrador/disciplinas/deletar/{{ $disciplina->id }}">Excluir</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>

                        {
                            return '\administrador/configuracoes'
                        }

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Após o procedimento de exclusão do registro você pode utilizar o `helper`

`back()` definido no Laravel.

Veja a documentação da função [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-back).

```
return back();
```

Que retornará para a mesma página de origem.

Answer (score 0):

```
return redirect(/pagina que você quer)
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor como essa resposta pode ser aplicada?

Comment: Se você estiver fazendo um cadastro, e depois de finalizado quer voltar pra página de formulário sem o POST, usa isso.